# How to iterate over JSON array using robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I want to iterate over json response and get the id and name elements data .My response json and code that i am trying is below. Can someone let me know what mistake i am doing .

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "policyRevId": 3,
    "busId": "POL_0003",
    "revision": 1,
    "name": "CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 v2.2.1"
    },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "policyRevId": 2,
    "busId": "POL_0002",
    "revision": 1,
    "name": "CIS SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Benchmark v 2.0"

  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "policyRevId": 1,
    "busId": "POL_0001",
    "revision": 1,
    "name": "Payment Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard version 3.1"
  }
]


*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           strings


*** Test case ***

Get Policy With Auth
    @{auth}=  Create List  user  pass
    Create Session    httpbin    https://test123.com/  auth=@{auth}
    ${resp}=  Get Request  httpbin  uri=/policies/
    :FOR   ${i}   in  ${resp.json()}
    \   Log  ${i}
    \   ${get_policy_id}=    Get Variable Value    ${resp.json()[i]['id']}
    \   ${policy_name}=    Get Variable Value    ${resp.json()[i]['name']}
    \   Log    ${policy_id},${policy_name}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? How is the output of this code different than what you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley , I want to iterate over the dictionary and get id,name values . I am getting output as None. resp.json() contains the keyvalues pairs

Comment: When you log `${i}`, what shows up in the log?

Comment: ` [{u'measurementSLO': u'1 Month', u'organization': {u'id': 1, u'name': u'public'}, u'busId': u'POL_0012', u'name': u'CIS Apache Tomcat Server 6.0 Benchmark v1.0.0', u'createdDT': 1473850353122L, u'description':ersonnel who plan to develop, deploy, assess, or secure solutions that incorporate Apache Tomcat on a Linux platform', u'signature': u'4698', u'submittedDT': None, u'lifeCycle': u'Production',None, u'id': 3}]`   . I have copied some sample data from the log . Thanks for your response @BryanOakley

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data in `${resp.json()}` is a list, so you should be able to directly iterate over the items in the list. Notice in the following example that `@` is used in the `:FOR` statement, and that `${item}` is a dictionary rather than an index:

```
:FOR   ${item}   in  @{resp.json()}
\   Log  ${item}
\   ${get_policy_id}=  Set variable    ${item['id']}
\   ${policy_name}=    Set variable    ${item['name']}
\   Log    ${policy_id},${policy_name}
```

Comment: @Madhu you can even consider to upvote the answer :)